# Workbox: clean up cache

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

It doesn't seem like workbox cleans up old caches. For example, if I specify a cache version like this:

```
var version = 'v2';
workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({
  suffix: version
});
```

...I would have expected workbox to clean up older versions of the cache once the new service worker activates, but my cache storage looks like this:

[image]

Is it safe to manually clean up caches myself? For example in my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches
      .keys()
      .then(keys => keys.filter(key => !key.endsWith(version)))
      .then(keys => Promise.all(keys.map(key => caches.delete(key))))
  );
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are changing the `suffix` property value to a string that you are as a version. But Workbox only uses it to name the bucket for caching.

[From the Workbox docs.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-core)

> The main use case for the prefix and suffix is that if you use Workbox for multiple projects and use the same localhost for each project, setting a custom prefix for each module will prevent the caches from conflicting with each other.

Workbox doesn't think of `x-v2` as the new replacement for `x-v1`.

You can use your cache eviction strategy just fine since Workbox will no longer use the previously named caches.

However you shouldn't need to use `suffix` to version your assets. Workbox has a number of tools to make sure assets are updated correctly. Plus your `suffix` implementation will always start out with a fresh cache and download everything.

### [precache](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching)

Precache has revisions for assets so as the assets change, you generate a new build, and deploy the changed assets will update and the unchanged assets will be left alone.

### [strategies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies)

Strategies is where most of the work will be done. When you are defining routes you will define the caching strategy the fits best with that type of asset. `staleWhileRevalidate` is a great approach where the on-device cache will be used but Workbox will also hit the network in parallel and check if there are updates to that resource.

### [expiration](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cache-expiration)

You can also make sure that old assets purged if they become older than the defined expiration length.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you.

Comment: Ok just to understand it again. I don't need to delete the cache, because Workbox is handling it automatically? My problem is that in my browser with a local host, I still need to delete the server worker manually, because it does not want to update the code, even though the precache file got a new name. Now I'm not sure if I should implement a safety clear like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376355/clear-workbox-cache-of-all-content)